# What kind of datatype will be set in Pentaho kettle?

Tags: types, pentaho, kettle

I have a question about kettle performance tuning. The question is：

We use kettle to get data from Oracle database

```
CREATE TABLE demo_table(demo_field varchar(2000));
INSERT INTO demo_table(demo_field) values('1');
```

We use kettle component table input, so when kettle get data from this table, how much memory space will it use in kettle? According to the datatype length or the real length?

Also another component select values, you can select type, if type is none what does this mean?

Comment: Java programmers do not need to distinguish among the three types of JDBC strings, CHAR, VARCHAR, and LONGVARCHAR. Each can be expressed as a Java String, and it is possible to read and write an SQL statement correctly without knowing the exact data type that was expected.  Precisely u can take any profiler to look how much exactly of memory takes certain length String.

Comment: I can't find "None" type in "Select Values" step.  If you mean "None" in case when u don't assign field type explicitly, then kettle will try to guess it. I am personally prefer always to assign type explicitly, since i had experience when kettle parse Integers it uses default #,# pattern and as result field has float type instead of integer which leads to errors.